# Magento 2 - get store specific product name and description

Tags: magento2

1. My shop has 6 store views: DE, AT, IT, ES, FR, GB
2. Each store view uses the same set of product (but appriopriate translated)

Now, I would like to get product name from IT only for example. How do I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: In what context? Get IT product name where?

Comment: It's happening in Controller execute() function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
protected $_productFactory;
```

in `construct` add this

```
  public function __construct(     
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $_productFactory
    ) {
        $this->_productFactory = $_productFactory;        
    }
```

now you can use this like,

```
$product= $this->_productFactory->create()->setStoreId($storeId)->load($pid);
```

Where `$storeId` is your store Id and `$pid` is your product Id.

```
$productName=$product->getName();
```

Don't forget to do `di:compile` by

`php bin/magento setup:di:compile` and clear `cache`

`php bin/magento c:f`

**EDIT**

For `productRepository`

```
protected $productRepository;
```

in `construct` add this

```
 public function __construct(     
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,

    ) {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }
```

Now, you can  use this

`$this->productRepository->getById($pid,false,$storeId);`

You can see It's arguments in

`vendor\magento\module-catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface.php`

`public function getById($productId, $editMode = false, $storeId = null, $forceReload = false);`

Comment: I'm using Product Repository and would prefer to stick with it. Any other solutions?

Comment: See my edit .. @PeteJaworski