# Fetch product from only one store view

Tags: magento2

I have 4 store view. In this store view i have products. Store view differ in the names of products. I want to fetch product only from one storeview. Now i can fetch product from main, first store view. How can i switch store view to fetch product from second store view where product have different name.

Comment: check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/177502/magento-2-get-store-specific-product-name-and-description?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: can you post your current code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding, i think you have to get store specific product name and other product data. you can achieve these things using below code.

**Load product factory in construct method**

```
protected $_productFactory;

public function __construct(     
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $_productFactory
) {
    $this->_productFactory = $_productFactory;        
}
```

Now you can use like below.

```
$product= $this->_productFactory->create()->setStoreId($storeId)->load($pid);
$productName=$product->getName();
```

Where **$storeId** is your store Id and **$pid** is your product Id.

You can also use product repository `(\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository)` instead of product factory `(\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory)`

I hope it helps!