# Magento 2: Load store specific product

Tags: magento2

How can I get store specific products. Mysql query will also work. Can some one help me on this. Thanks.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/177502/magento-2-get-store-specific-product-name-and-description

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

class Product extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{    
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,        
        array $data = []
    )
    {    
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;    
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getProductCollection()
    {
        $storeId = 1; //Store ID
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $collection->addStoreFilter($storeId);        
        return $collection;
    }
}
?>
```

change your `Store ID`.

Hope this will work!

Comment: I tried it in same way but when I am trying to print query it is giving me this result SELECT `e`.* FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` INNER JOIN `catalog_product_website` AS `product_website` ON product_website.product_id = e.entity_id AND product_website.website_id = '1' WHERE (e.created_in <= 1) AND (e.updated_in > 1)
It is checking with website id and not store id.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this might will help you.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

class Product extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
 {    
  protected $productFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,        
    array $data = []
)
{    
    $this->productFactory = $productFactory;    
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

public function getProduct($storeId, $productId) {
    $product = $this->productFactory->create()
                            ->setStoreId($storeId)
                            ->load($productId);
    return $product;
}

public function getProductCollection($storeId)
{
    $productCollection = $this->productFactory->create()
                                ->setStoreId($storeId)
                                ->getCollection()
                                ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    return $productCollection;
}
}
```